# Sessions with http-client

Tags: haskell

Say I want to make two requests. The first one sends login information to the server and the second one retrieves some data that requires authentication.

Is there anything special I need to do to get this behavior with `http-client`? The way it worked with `wreq` is by sharing the same `Session` value in both requests. The cookies and everything got handled automatically.

I assumed the same would be true with `http-client` if I share the same `Manager` but this doesn't seem to be the case. I get a response indicating that I'm not logged in.

Unfortunately I can't really provide a compilable code sample for various reasons.

Comment: @mb21 It's just a Reader wrapped around a Manager. If that's an indication that sharing the manager should be all that's needed, then I guess my problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you see the section on [cookies](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#g:14)?

Comment: @RowanBlush I did but it doesn't say whether I should update the cookie jar manually or what.

Comment: Yeah, you've gotta plumb that sucker around yourself.

Comment: @RowanBlush Hmm, ok. I guess it's a good thing that the porting from `wreq` to `http-client` left my code in a way that doing this is pretty easy. If you're sure about this and want to make it an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have to manage the cookie jar yourself with the functions [createCookieJar](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:createCookieJar), [updateCookieJar](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:updateCookieJar) and [insertCookiesIntoRequest](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:insertCookiesIntoRequest).

Some example code:

```
import Network.HTTP.Client
import Network.HTTP.Types.Status (statusCode)
import Data.Time.Clock

main :: IO ()
main = do
  manager <- newManager defaultManagerSettings

  now1 <- getCurrentTime
  request1 <- parseRequest "http://cnn.com"
  response1 <- httpLbs request1 manager

  putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++ (show $ statusCode $ responseStatus response1)
  -- print $ responseBody response

  let (jar1, _) = updateCookieJar response1 request1 now1 (createCookieJar [])
  putStrLn $ "new jar: " ++ show jar1

  req2 <- parseRequest "http://cnn.com"
  now2 <- getCurrentTime
  let (request2, jar2) = insertCookiesIntoRequest req2 jar1 now2

  response2 <- httpLbs request2 manager

  putStrLn $ "\nThe status code was: " ++ (show $ statusCode $ responseStatus response2)
  -- print $ responseBody response2
```